# Having a Twitter Bootstrap tab keep its place when going to another tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When switching to another tab in Bootstrap, the user always starts looking at the tab content at the top. I want to know if there's a way to scroll to where the user was previously looking at when returning to a tab.

Details:

I defined my list of tabs like so:

```
<ul id="main_tab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#users_tab_content" data-toggle="tab">Users</a></li>

Then there are more <li> values under the <ul>.
Then the content starts like so:

<div id="main_tab_content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="users_tab_content">

Of course, with more <div> content tabs under the main <div>.
```

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing any code. Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what you are saying without looking at any code. Are you using regular tabs or JavaScript tags?

I'll go on a hunch and guess you are using JavaScript tabs. This should not happen, so I would suggest you look at your markup carefully. Usually, there's a `preventDefault()` call in the JS that stops the page from jumping.

Make sure you have your ids referenced correctly in your links:

```
<a href="#some_location">
```